# HttpPost data not coming over

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am creating an Angularjs application and have everything working pretty well with get and edit messages. Now I want to add new and delete capabilities.

I have a controller named SkillsController:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[RoutePrefix("api/skills")]
public class SkillsController : ApiControllerBase
{
    public SkillsController(IDataRepository dataRepository) : base(dataRepository)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("get")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return CreateHttpResponse(request, () =>
        {
            List<Skill> skills = DataRepository.GetSkills();
            return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, skills);
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("update")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Update(HttpRequestMessage request, Skill skill)
    {
        return CreateHttpResponse(request, () =>
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(k => ModelState[k].Errors)
                          .Select(m => m.ErrorMessage).ToArray());
            }
            else
            {
                DataRepository.UpdateSkill(skill);
                response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }

            return response;
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("create")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Create(HttpRequestMessage request, Skill skill)
    {
        return CreateHttpResponse(request, () =>
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(k => ModelState[k].Errors)
                          .Select(m => m.ErrorMessage).ToArray());
            }
            else
            {
                response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }

            return response;
        });
    }
}
}
```

And I have a skillsCtrl.js file:

```
(function (app) {
'use strict';

app.controller('skillsCtrl', skillsCtrl);

skillsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$modal', 'apiService', 'notificationService'];

function skillsCtrl($scope, $modal, apiService, notificationService) {
    $scope.pageClass = 'page-skills';
    $scope.loadingSkills = true;
    $scope.Skills = [];

    $scope.loadSkills = loadSkills;
    $scope.createSkill = createSkill;
    $scope.deleteSkill = deleteSkill;
    $scope.openEditDialog = openEditDialog;

    function loadSkills() {
        $scope.loadingLevels = true;

        apiService.get('/api/skills/get/', null,
            skillsLoadCompleted,
            skillsLoadFailed);
    }

    function createSkill() {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'scripts/spa/skills/newSkill.html',
            controller: 'skillNewCtrl',
            scope: $scope
        }).result.then(function ($scope) {
        }, function () {
        });
    }

    function openEditDialog(skill) {
        $scope.EditedSkill = skill;
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'scripts/spa/skills/editSkill.html',
            controller: 'skillEditCtrl',
            scope: $scope
        }).result.then(function ($scope) {
        }, function () {
        });
    }

    function skillsLoadCompleted(result) {
        $scope.Skills = result.data;
        $scope.loadingSkills = false;
    }

    function skillsLoadFailed(response) {
        notificationService.displayError(response.data);
    }

    $scope.loadSkills();
}
})(angular.module('appSkills'));
```

Then I have a skillEditCtrl.js file and it works perfectly:

```
(function (app) {
'use strict';

app.controller('skillEditCtrl', skillEditCtrl);

skillEditCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$modalInstance', '$timeout', 'apiService', 'notificationService'];

function skillEditCtrl($scope, $modalInstance, $timeout, apiService, notificationService) {
    $scope.cancelEdit = cancelEdit;
    $scope.updateSkill = updateSkill;

    function updateSkill() {
        apiService.post('/api/skills/update/', $scope.EditedSkill,
            updateSkillCompleted,
            updateSkillLoadFailed);
    }

    function updateSkillCompleted(response) {
        notificationService.displaySuccess($scope.EditedSkill.SkillName + ' has been updated');
        $scope.EditedSkill = {};
        $modalInstance.dismiss();
    }

    function updateSkillLoadFailed(response) {
        notificationService.displayError(response.data);
    }

    function cancelEdit() {
        $scope.isEnabled = false;
        $modalInstance.dismiss();
    }
}
})(angular.module('appSkills'));
```

And a skillsNewCtrl.js file:

```
(function (app) {
'use strict';

app.controller('skillNewCtrl', skillNewCtrl);

skillNewCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$modalInstance', '$timeout', 'apiService', 'notificationService'];

function skillNewCtrl($scope, $modalInstance, $timeout, apiService, notificationService) {
    $scope.newSkill = { SkillId: 0, SkillName: "test" };
    $scope.cancelCreate = cancelCreate;
    $scope.createSkill = createSkill;

    function createSkill() {
        apiService.post('/api/skills/create/', $scope.newSkill,
            createSkillCompleted,
            createSkillLoadFailed);
    }

    function createSkillCompleted(response) {
        notificationService.displaySuccess($scope.newSkill.SkillName + ' has been updated');
        $modalInstance.dismiss();
    }

    function createSkillLoadFailed(response) {
        notificationService.displayError(response.data);
    }

    function cancelCreate() {
        $scope.isEnabled = false;
        $modalInstance.dismiss();
    }
}
})(angular.module('appSkills'));
```

This call works fine, I get a properly formed Skill object in the Update method on the controller:

```
            apiService.post('/api/skills/update/', $scope.EditedSkill,
            createSkillCompleted,
            createSkillLoadFailed);
```

The Create method gets called just fine, but the Skills object is null:

```
            apiService.post('/api/skills/create/', $scope.newSkill,
            createSkillCompleted,
            createSkillLoadFailed);
```

I know this is a lot to go through, but I have been banging my head against this issue for 4 hours. I have tried everything.

Comment: The biggest difference is that an edited skill is an actual skill object from the load function. The new skill is defined as a json object. How do you do the mapping between them?

Comment: Another issue is editing errors display for the Edit screen but not for the New screen. What's up with that? I am very new to Angular.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object".](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)  JSON is a string notation for representing objects, nothing more.

Comment: You know what I meant by JSON object. I'm new to Angular not a dummy :)

Comment: Yes, I knew what you meant.  You can choose to continue saying "JSON object" and continue to be viewed as a novice (and corrected), or you can update your terminology so it is correct.  I did not suggest you are a dummy.

Comment: It's fixed. It actually never was broken. Setting a break on the method showed skill was null. But after setting breakpints on the properties in Skill, I not it was getting set. Stepped through and the object was not null after all. Craze.

Comment: In that case I suggest you simply delete this question, otherwise it will be closed as a typographical error.

Comment: @NickV W3Schools is terrible, and wrong in this case. If you never go there again you'll be better off.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Create(HttpRequestMessage request, Skill skill)
```

to:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Create(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromBody] Skill skill)
```